# Validation issue on django form submit for CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-validation

I Have a form like Given below :

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E62gL.png
```

code what i am writting is like given below.

```
class CustomBookingFeatureCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def my_choices():
        value = Features.objects.values()
        features = []
        for feature in value:
            features.append([feature['id'], feature['name']])
        return features

    feature = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=my_choices, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    class Meta:
        model = BookingFeature
        fields = ['feature']
```

when i am submitting the form its returning me the error like this how can i save this form with multipl choices please help me related tgis i am a newbe in django .. please suggest me a best way to solve this

Models I have For Linking Is Given Below:

```
class Features(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Active'),
        (0, 'Inactive'),
        (2, 'Deleted'),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(
        _('status'), choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "features"
        verbose_name = 'Features'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Features'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class BookingFeature(models.Model):
    booking = models.ForeignKey(Booking,on_delete=models.CASCADE ,null=False,blank=False)
    feature = models.OneToOneField(Features,on_delete=models.CASCADE ,null=False,blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "booking_features"
        verbose_name = 'Booking Features'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Booking Features'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.feature
```

Comment: Can you share your `BookingFeature` model? I have the idea that your model has a `ForeignKey`, and not a `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: i also tried it with ManyToManyField but after doing this i have not found any column in table to save this in table..

Comment: no, it will then create an extra table in the database that acts as a "junction table".

Comment: Although it likely makes more sense *not* to write a `BookingFeature` model (yourself), and construct a `ManyToManyField` between `Booking` and `Feature`.

Comment: can you please explain in brief ?? i am not getting your point i am stuck here from last one day not getting any solutions.. or any example if you have pleaselet me know i would be very greatfull to you..

Comment: or what should be the structure of model for that type of cases..

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what happen any solution ??

Comment: Also i have tried with the many to many but getting issue like : Cannot assign "['1', '2', '3', '4']": "BookingFeature.feature" must be a "Features" instance.